# Qual o uso de window.history.replaceState?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

Olá, eu gostaria de saber o que o seguinte código faz:

```
window.history.replaceState
```

Comment: Nada, está comentado. RÁ! Acho melhor você ler a documentação champz : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method

Comment: http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/05/05/mudando-a-barra-de-endereco-do-browser-sem-refresh/

Answer (score 4):

Os métodos [*history.pushState()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method) e [*history.replaceState()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method) foram introduzidos no **HTML5** para conseguir recuperar e modificar valores durante o histórico de navegação do usuário.

Ambos métodos funcionam da mesma maneira, a única diferença é que o `pushState` adiciona um novo estado no histórico enquanto que o `replaceState` sobrescreve o estado que foi colocado pelo `pushState`.

Os dois possuem três parâmetros: **state object**, **title** e **URL**.

- **state object** — É o objeto que vai ficar associado com aquele determinado histórico criado pelo `pushState()`. Quando o usuário usa o botão de voltar no navegador ou pelo `history.go(-1)` é possível recuperar esse objeto através do evento chamado [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate). Além do objeto precisa ser [serializável](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_seri.htm).
- **title** — é um título opcional, ignorado até o momento.
- **URL** — modifica a `URL` que aparece no navegador, mas não redireciona realmente pra essa `URL` é apenas visual.

### Exemplo:

1. Crie um arquivo teste.html
2. Adicione o seguinte código dele e abra-a no navegador.

```
<script>
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      alert("url: " + document.location + ", objeto: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
    };

    // cria o primeiro estado no histórico
    history.pushState({pagina: 1}, "titulo 1", "?pagina=1");

    // cria o segundo estado no histórico
    history.pushState({pagina: 2}, "titulo 2", "?pagina=2");

    // sobrescreve o estado atual (2) por um novo
    history.replaceState({pagina: 3}, "titulo 3", "?pagina=3");

    // volta uma pagina, você estava no (3) volta pro (1), pois o (2) foi sobrescrito
    history.back(); // alerts "url: .../exemplo.html?pagina=1, objeto: {"pagina":1}"

    // volta pra primeira pagina onde não tinha nenhum estado criado ainda, pois você já volto uma e esta no (1)
    history.back(); // alerts "url: .../exemplo.html, objeto: null

    // avança 2 páginas, estava no "null", passou pelo (1) e voltou pro (3)
    history.go(2);  // alerts "url: .../exemplo.html?pagina=3, state: {"pagina":3}

</script>
```

Fique utilizando o *voltar* e *avançar* do navegador para perceber os **alerts**.

### Uma coisa importante!

Se você quiser ficar transitando objetos pelos estados do histórico que são **MUITO** grandes, o recomendável é utilizar *sessionStorage* ou *localStorage*.

### Quer brincar mais com o `pushState` e `replaceState`?

http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/history-pushstate/index.html

É um ótimo exemplo de como trabalhar com esses métodos.

### Fontes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-history-pushstate/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history