# O que é SPA e no que se diferencia de uma página não SPA?

Tags: terminologia, single-page-application

Lendo este [outro post do SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81205/o-que-s%C3%A3o-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-isomorphic) que fala sobre: aplicações *isomorphic*, é comentado em uma resposta sobre SPA.

O que é uma Single Page Application? E qual a diferença de uma página SPA para uma página não SPA? O que muda em questões de performance e em questões de SEO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma SPA (Single Page Aplication) é uma aplicação que [não recarrega a página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129) durante o seu tempo de vida.

Ou porque a informação cabe somente numa página, ou usando [navegação no lado do cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26078/129), a janela do navegador nunca é recarregada.

À medida que o JavaScript foi ficando mais avançado começou a ser possivel via ajax ir buscar dados ao servidor e a outros serviços sem ter de recarregar a página com dados novos no HTML. Assim frameworks como Backbone.js, React, Vue, Angular tornaram essa norma algo muito usado.

Caso a aplicação seja mesmo de uma página só então não precisa de Router, mas nas aplicações maiores pode mesmo ter-se um [Router no lado do cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26078/129) para simular mudança de páginas e usando o [pushState](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70726/129) pode mesmo mudar-se o endereço no navegador sem ter de carregar a página.

Um exemplo de SPA (muito simples, baseado num jsFiddle do [Eduardo](https://github.com/posva)) com Vue.js seria por exemplo:

```js
const Principal = {
  template: '<h1>Página Principal</h1>'
}
const Secundaria = {
  template: '<h1>Página Secundária</h1>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
      path: '/principal',
      component: Principal
    },
    {
      path: '/secundaria',
      component: Secundaria
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/principal">Pagina principal</router-link>
  <router-link to="/secundaria">Pagina secundária</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55ca496g/**

Neste exemplo há dois componentes que preenchem o corpo da página. Assim dependendo de qual dos componentes estamos a usar via Router temos partes diferentes da aplicação, que parecem duas páginas diferentes mas na verdade é uma SPA.