# Passando parâmetro pela URL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

como vocês fazem para passar um parâmetro para outra tela da VIEW, sem que o usuário veja ele na URL?

Por exemplo : Tenho uma tela de consulta que o usuário clica na tabela e é redirecionado para outra tela, que é a tela que abre as informações do campo que foi clicado, no caso pode ser um código.

a url ficaria assim :

http://localhost:64654/pim/romaneio/Index?pId=108491

Passo ela por JS, assim :

```
window.location = "Index?pId=" + $($(this).find('td').get(0)).text();
```

Meu problema é que vou precisar passar um parâmetro, para indicar se os campos da tela poderão ou não estar habilitados.

Passando ele pela URL deixaria aplicação vulnerável a alterações, como posso proceder?

Comment: Olá tenta o método POST: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Comment: De qualquer forma vai ficar vulnerável a alterações. Isso é péssimo pra segurança, você deveria validar isso apenas do lado do servidor.

Comment: Existe outra forma de passar parâmetro entra a Visão e o Controller?

Comment: tens razão @LINQ , tente verificar no lado de servidor , tenta encriptar se possivel

Comment: @AndersonApdodeSouza Não existe "passagem" de parâmetro entre views e controllers. **Absolutamente tudo** são requisições HTTP, você precisa ter ciência disso.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, eu tenho um tabela que lista valores, aí o usuário clica no valor 1, e esse valor precisa levar a outra tela que um método recebe ele e vai até o banco buscar. No caso preciso fazer tudo isso dentro do meu controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua descrição, parece que o objeto `window` pode fazer isso por você:

```
var link = "" // Seu link aqui.
var newWindow = window.open(link, "_blank");

newWindow.paramTeste = "Este parâmetro foi transferido de uma pagina a outra.";
```

Caso de teste: https://jsfiddle.net/0tgLeyL5/

Ao clicar no botão *Redirecionar*, uma nova aba (ou janela) em branco vai ser aberta (poderia ser qualquer outro link para onde você quisesse ser redirecionado). Dentro do console (no `F12`), se você escrever `window.paramTeste`, vai ver que a variável estará definida. Você pode transferir qualquer objeto de uma janela/aba à outra desse jeito, sem a necessidade de outros métodos mais complexos.

Vale lembrar que esse método ainda te deixa vulnerável a mudanças feitas pelo usuário. É apenas menos óbvio, mas ainda assim fácil de manipular.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe forma de se passar informações de uma máquina cliente a uma máquina servidora que seja a prova de alterações da informação passada. Lide com isso.

Se você quiser dificultar muito a vida de um hacker, você pode fazer com que seus usuários sejam obrigados a usar um aplicativo ao invés de uma página.

Fora isso... Se você quer apenas evitar que usuários leigos possam ver os valores de parâmetros na URL, você tem algumas opções:

- [Fazer uma SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212952/1658);
- Usar POST ao invés de GET;
- Fazer uma requisição AJAX para o servidor, obter os resultados, e então montá-los em tela. Tem a ver com a primeira alternativa tangencialmente, mas não requer necessariamente esforço para repensar o seu sistema nesse momento. Segue um pseudo-código de exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    url: "Index?pId=" + $($(this).find('td').get(0)).text(),
    success: function (resultado) {
        // obtenha o resultado aqui e coloque em algum componente da página
    }
})
```

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso, dessa forma eu consigo sair da pagina consulta e ir para a página index?

Perdoe minha ignorância, sou um iniciante nesse mundo de requisições... e protocolos web.

Comment: @AndersonApdodeSouza com a primeira alternativa (SPA) você nunca sai da mesma página. Com a segunda você consegue levar dados de uma página a outra sem precisar por parâmetros em URL. Com a terceira alternativa o que você quer não é possível.

Comment: Entendi, hoje por exemplo eu faço assim :


        $("#tbRomaneio tbody tr").on('click', function () {
            
            window.location = "Index?pId=" + $($(this).find('td').get(0)).text();
        });


Como eu faria nesse caso para passar os dados para a outra página, e redirecionar na sequência?

Comment: @AndersonApdodeSouza seus campos com os dados preenchidos pelo usuário devem estar dentro de um formulário. O atributo `action` do formulário deve ser a página de destino. Por fim, você precisa pressionar algum botão que faça submissão e que esteja dentro do formulário. Botões que realizam submissão são elementos `input` ou `button` com atributo `type="submit"`.

Comment: Então não vai dar certo. No meu caso, na hora que o usuário clica na table é que eu chamo o evento click e redireciono ele para outra VIEW que está na mesma pasta. 

Passando o valor da primeira td da table.

Comment: @AndersonApdodeSouza você não pode me ver mas eu estou fazendo a pose da Bela Gil na meme dela agora. Você pode substituir o clique do botão por `$("form").submit()`, por exemplo ;)

Comment: haha, @Renan, não é no botão, é na table.

Comment: @AndersonApdodeSouza `$(tabela).on("click", function () { $("form").submit(); });`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62996/discussion-between-anderson-apdo-de-souza-and-renan).