# Página em várias línguas

Tags: html

Como são feitas as páginas que estão disponíveis em vários idiomas?

Realmente são várias páginas em HTML *linkadas* feitas a mão em diferentes línguas ou tem alguma fórmula para isso?

Estou fazendo um site simples para mim mesmo e gostaria de disponibilizá-lo em vários idiomas como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer utilizar qual linguagem? Porque cada linguagem tem a sua ferramenta especifica.

Comment: Tem inúmeras maneiras de se fazer isso. A mais simples é tratar o idioma ainda no lado do servidor e montar o corpo da resposta com os textos traduzidos, podendo estes estarem armazenados em um arquivo ou em um banco de dados. Tem como fazer com JavaScript também, mas o tempo de carregamento da página tende a aumentar. Dito isso, acho que sua pergunta está ampla demais com os dados que foram postados. Se conseguir limitar mais o problema, quem sabe será possível responder.

Comment: @WictorChaves Ele falou "língua" e não "linguagem" :)

Comment: Acho que não fui claro, com língua quis dizer idioma.

Comment: Já fiz uma vez um site simples em português e inglês, mas como tinha pouco texto, eu apenas utilizei `if else` no lado servidor. No caso de ser um site de muito conteúdo, acho que é como o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou, armazenar em banco de dados ou arquivo todo o texto em cada idioma que for usar, e puxá-los de acordo com a opção do usuário.

Comment: @HenriqueBretone, sim eu entendi, mas é porque existe ferramentas prontas para isso, como o android por exemplo, ele tem um arquivo chamado "string.xml" onde você coloca o texto do app nele, você criar um para cada linguá que você  vai trabalhar.

Comment: Agradeço os comentários só queria saber como é feito essas páginas mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é uma ou várias páginas independe de ser em várias línguas isto será definido pela arquitetura geral de como o site é montado. Pode ser várias páginas, pode ser um modelo que tem os textos preenchidos com o que vem de um banco de dados ou arquivo de acordo com o que for selecionado, pode ser uma página única que carrega os textos com AJAX ou algo parecido.

Primeiro defina como fará em uma língua para depois definir como fará em várias.

Fazer uma só pagina para várias línguas dá mais trabalho do que as pessoas imaginam porque os textos não são do mesmo tamanho e isto cria complicadores. Por isto tem quem prefira fazer tudo na mão. Se fizer um modelo para usar em todas as línguas precisa ser muito bem feito para lidar com tamanhos de texto diferentes sem ficar esquisito, principalmente sem estourar texto, mas também deixando espaços indevidos.

Se fizer isto tem que decidir onde colocará os textos, geralmente é em um banco de dados. Daí precisa decidir se as páginas serão geradas dinamicamente ou [estaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239672/101). Idealmente os textos devem ser carregados e usados conforme demanda em variáveis ou mapas (*arrays* associativos mesmo), nem `if` precisa, já que o identificador do idioma já determina quais textos serão pegos.

Se optar por captar os textos por AJAX não deve ser um site porque pode ter problemas de indexação.

Lembre-se que imagens que possuem texto precisam ser diferentes, então URLs delas devem ser diferenciadas também.

Nem entrei no mérito de alfabetos bem diferentes do nosso (romano) e escritas em outra direção, afinal é raro fazermos para idiomas tão diferentes.

Obviamente que os detalhes de como fazer podem variar muito e isto é muito amplo para responder sem saber a necessidade.