# Framework para single page application

Tags: seo, route

Estou a montar um website estático e queria fazer este site ser um Single Page Application. Eu tenho ciencia de que sendo um SPA há várias complicações com SEO. Pergunto a vocês, existe algum framework que não tenha esse problema com SEO e que dê para fazer o SPA?

Eu não queria usar um framework do tipo VueJS, Angular para isso, porque eu não vou usar nada deles, apenas o roteamento.

Existe algum framework que faça um SPA simples e sem/pouco problemas de SEO?

Obrigado Devs!!

Comment: site estático? acho que esse termo está errado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239672/o-que-%c3%a9-um-gerador-de-site-est%c3%a1tico , se você está falando desse tipo de gerador, sim é possível fazer SPA neles de maneira simples

Comment: Site estático que eu diga é  aquele que você vai no HTML e codifica na raça do zero

Comment: Hmmm entendi. Eu consigo apenas importar o Router do Vue. Legal! E você conhece algum artigo ou tutorial em que eu consiga conciliar o SEO com o SPA? Obrigado!

Comment: Respondi para ficar mais organizado

Answer (score 3):

Creio que ninguém usaria uma framework somente para roteamento, caso você use `Angularjs` basta importar o `angular route`, e gerenciar as rotas de maneira fácil, porém o `Angularjs` é bem burocrático e dificulta muito a utilização de `J-query` por exemplo, por isso recomendo `Vue.Js` ou `React.Js`, como disse basta usar o módulo que precisas, não tudo.

Em termos de `SEO` técnicas como `ajax-crawling` foram descontinuadas você pode se atualizar [aqui](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html), como pode ver, o google hoje consegue indexar suas rotas seguindo algumas exigências básicas, na [gringa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549306/single-page-js-websites-and-seo) você consegue bastante informações também.

Comment: Show! Só queria um site simples que tivesse a experiencia de um SPA (Rápido, sem reload) =)