# Deixar marcado o item selecionado no menu

Tags: javascript

Eu peguei esse exemplo de menu

```js
 $(function(){
        var menu = $('.menu-navigation-round');
        menu.slicknav();
        // Mark the clicked item as selected
        menu.on('click', 'a', function(){
                    var a = $(this);
            a.siblings().removeClass('selected');
            a.addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

```html
                            
<nav class="menu-navigation-round">
      <a href="/" class="selected"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
       <a href="/search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Busca</a>
       <a href="#"> Anuncie seu imóvel</a>
       <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contato</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Sobre nós</a>    
</nav>
```

A classe selected sempre volta para a origem se eu trocar de pagina. Quando estou usando o # o código funciona normalmente e fica selecionado a correta, mas se eu apertar em Busca por exemplo, que vai para outra pagina, o menu seleciona ela mas na atualização da pagina ela volta a ficar marcado a opção Home novamente.

---

EDIT

```html
<div class="user-menu alignright"> 


  {$page = 'busca'}  
  
   <nav class="menu-navigation-round">
   <a href="/"  {if="$page == 'home'"}Class="selected"{else}""{/if}><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
   
   <a href="/search" {if="$page == 'busca'"}Class="selected"{else}""{/if} ><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Busca</a>
   
   <a href="#" {if="$page == 'anuncie'"}Class="selected"{else}""{/if} ><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> Anuncie seu imóvel</a>
   
   <a href="#" {if="$page == 'contato'"}Class="selected"{else}""{/if} ><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contato</a>
   
   <a href="#" {if="$page == 'sobre'"}Class="selected"{else}""{/if} ><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Sobre nós</a>   
   </nav>                 
</div>
```

Fiz essa mudança agora se a variavel page for igual ao nome da url ele coloca a classe selected, e funciona direitinho, mas eu nao sei como fazer para mudar o valor da variavel page, se fosse em JS seria o onclick, mas como que eu faço em php isso? ou de qualquer forma que funcione assim.

Comment: Da forma que foi feito, está estruturado para [SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212952/o-que-%C3%A9-spa-e-no-que-se-diferencia-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-n%C3%A3o-spa). Ao carregar o DOM, o primeiro link já vem com a classe `.selected`. O que você precisa é carregar já com a classe no `a` referente ao DOM carregado. Ou então fazer uma função JavaScript a ser executada quando o DOM estiver totalmente carregado e adicionar a classe no `a` correto, baseando-se na URI... Para uma aplicação grande, a segunda opção não vai ser nada dinâmica...

Comment: Atribui o valor a uma variavel no PHP e fiz ela adicionar a classe "selected", agora só falta conseguir mudar o valor da variavel $page, não estou conseguindo pensar uma maneira  :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*- [...] eu nao sei como fazer para mudar o valor da variavel page [...]*"

Essa variável deve receber a `REQUEST_URI` devidamente *parseada*.

Veja como fica:

```
$page = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Quando você acessar `http://seusite.com.br/search`, a variável `$page` vai receber `/search`.

O interessante é que o `parse_url` não vai retornar possíveis dados passados via `GET`: `http://seusite.com.br/search?q=termo_da_busca` vai retornar o `/search` normalmente.

> Leituras recomendadas: [PHP - parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [PHP - $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.